# Hope to get guide how to handle image upload & show

Tags: image, meteor

I am now working on one Meteor project and trying to do the below.

I have a product list page and when I click one product, I goes to product edit page.

What I want to know is how to attach product image and show it when I go back to product list page.

I know CollectionFS used for file upload, but because there is no reliable guide to show detail, I am getting trouble for it.

I added this to schema, but don't know how to show product image in list page.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images")]
});

Images.allow({
 insert: function(){
 return true;
 },
 update: function(){
 return true;
 },
 remove: function(){
 return true;
 },
 download: function(){
 return true;
 }
});
Schemas.Products = new SimpleSchema({
  'name': {
    type: String,
    label: 'What is the name of the building?',
    max: 200,
    unique: true
  },
  'picture': {
    type: String, 
    max: 200,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: 'fileUpload',
        collection: 'Images',
        accept: 'image/*',
        label: 'Choose file'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Is there anyone can give me a direction? Please help me!

The goal in here is to show product image in product list page.

Comment: You may check out `yogiben:autoform-file` which extends `aldeed:autoform` and makes the upload/download process quite easy. However, it has a few issues.

Comment: Hi Blaze, Thanks for your contact. I already checked yogiben:autoform-file package, but it seems there is no any detailed example which is similar with my case.

Comment: And what I've got while I use yogiben:autoform-file in edit page is this.
          {{> afQuickField name="name"}}
          {{> afQuickField name="picture"}}
After saving, I've got this info.  
  name: "Product #1"
  picture: "r2qaNCfvSSWZDRv7N"
Now I need to show product image in list page by this picture string???

Comment: Did you publish `Images` from server? Check if you have any errors in your browser console.

Comment: I published Images from server, but where should I subscribe it?

Comment: You need to subscribe to it from anywhere in the client-side. If you only need the subscription in the current template, you can do a [`template.subscribe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104941/discussion-between-samuel-jansson-and-blaze-sahlzen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this really helpful [wiki](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Display-an-Uploaded-Image) on CollectionFS's page. It shows how to display an already uploaded image from front-end.

CollectionFS provides an `url` method associated with its `FS.File` object. Using this method we can display the image from frontend.

Steps:

1. Publish `Images` (`FS.Collection` instance) from server-side.
2. Subscribe to the above from your client-side.
3. In your template-helper, `return Images.find()` to the template.

*You can embed the result of `Images.find()` into the result from another collection as well. For example:*

```
var products = Products.find().fetch();
products.forEach(function(each) {
    each.file = Images.findOne({ _id: each.file });
});
return products;
```

4. Inside the template, you can display the image using:

```
<img src="{{this.url stores='images'}}" />
```

*Here `this` refers to the `FS.File` instance and `'images'` is the store name.*